# Stipe Checkout Barcelona vs now

Tags: 8, users

So I happily stumbled upon the video ['Shut up and take my money'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXVfkzqiOtk) from DrupalCon Barcelona (2015) to learn about the module 'stripe_checkout'. Notwithstanding my undying admiration for Drupal Commerce, I fully concur with the speaker that not all sites that want people to give them money need an entire Commerce Interface.

I was able to (navigating beyond the update-esoterica) mirror the behavior from the video on my sandbox, then the client site.

I very foolishly promised the solution to my client before remembering to test as an anonymous user.

It is quite clear that the Barelona Video version prompted for Email, then CC data. However, the current stripe_checkout gathers the email from the Logged in User, and FAILS COMPLETELY for anonymous users. Unless I am missing something (always a possibility) there is no 'config setting' for allowing/disallowing for anonymous users.

So my questions:
1) Has anyone out there already cleared this hurdle with some glueCode or some-such that could be shared here?
2) Or is there some other mechanism for clearing this hurdle short of implementing full-on Drupal Commerce?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Wasn't the downvoter, but I'm guessing it's because you're asking for free code or tutorials (strongly discouraged here). You might find a more receptive audience on its project page or more DC-centric channels (the .org forum, IRC, Slack, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I fully accept responsibility for my 'inappropriate' question, and thanks for those that posted helpful information about how to avoid the slings and arrows of StackExchange participation in the future. I do find myself flummoxed by all this, but I so completely find StackExchange answers of such a high quality I accept my confusion as a 'price of admission'. I do apologize in advance for additional faux pas in the future... indeed, perhaps this post.

So I solved it, with a direct code edit, not the proper glueCode that I will continue to work on. Notwithstanding, I am going to post my 'Psuedo-Diff' of the code changes I made to accomplish what I was looking for. With the caveat that I am 'breaking rules', perhaps others can find this a helpful jumping-off point for better expression of a similar solution.

I really need this for a project, so this is 'good enough' for me for this site for right now, but I fully intend to circle-back and attempt to solve this problem with proper glueCode or maybe even participation in the overall project. With that, I will say, 'So Long!' and post my Pseudo-Diff code below:

```
/**
 * @file: modules/contrib/stripe_checkout/src/Controller/StripeChargeController.php
 * @line: approx 64
 */
                        $amount = $node->$field_name->value;
                        $field_settings = $node->$field_name->getSettings();
                        $currency = $field_settings['currency'];
-                       $user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount();
+                       if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
+                               $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(10);
+                       /**
+                        * use whatever UID correlates to the dedicated 'anonymous payer'
+                        * you set up for this purpose, for me for this site is is User Number 10
+                        */
+                       } else {
+                               $user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount();
+                       }




/**
 * @file: modules/contrib/stripe_checkout/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/StripeCheckoutFormatter.php
 * @line: approx 92
 */
                $default_settings = $this::defaultSettings();
+               if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
+                        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(10);
+                       /**
+                        * use whatever UID correlates to the dedicated 'anonymous payer'
+                        * you set up for this purpose, for me for this site is is User Number 10
+                        */
+               } else {
+                       $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
+               }

/**
 * @file: modules/contrib/stripe_checkout/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/StripeCheckoutFormatter.php
 * @line: approx 127
 */
                                        'locale' => 'auto',
                                        // @todo Make configurable.
                                        'image' => 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
-                                       'email' => \Drupal::currentUser()->getEmail(),
                                        'label' => $link_text,
                                ],
                                '#is_free' => $is_free,
                                '#price' => $price,
                                '#entity_id' => $item->getEntity()->id(),
                                '#field_name' => $item->getFieldDefinition()->getName(),
-                               '#logged_in' => \Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated(),
+                               '#logged_in' => TRUE,

/**
 * @file: modules/contrib/stripe_checkout/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/StripeCheckoutFormatter.php
 * @line: approx 151
 */

+                       if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
+                               $elements[$delta]['#data']['email'] = $user->getEmail();
+                       }
```